# Can I get man pages without installing the corresponding packages?

Tags: manpage

Is there a way to have man pages available for commands i want without having to install the corresponding package?

For example, I want to browse the man page for `emacs`. And I don't have `emacs` installed and prefer not to install it. *I know i can visit man pages online* , but I want `man emacs` to get me the man page. Is there a way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the package.  Emacs isn't packaged in a way that you can.  For some packages you can `apt-get install basepackage-doc`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need an alternate way for packages/programs that don't have docs in a separate package.

Answer (score 6):

The [`dman`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/dman.1.html) command will automatically download a manual page to a temporary cache, and then show it. It's good for displaying manual pages for software that is not installed, though sometimes it doesn't work well, and you do have to wait for the manual page to download. (Manual pages are small though, so that doesn't usually take long.)

To get `dman`, install the [bikeshed [image: Install bikeshed]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bikeshed) package.

`dman`'s own man page notes:

> Note that the network operations will be a little slower  than 
>   perhaps
>          you  are  used  to, when reading a manpage.  Also note that you must be
>          internet-connected, and able to  access  manpages.ubuntu.com  for  this
>          utility  to  be  useful.   Finally,  the  algorithm  that  `dman` uses to
>          retrieve remote pages is considerably simpler than that of [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/man.1.html)(1).

`dman` may appear to do nothing at all, if it's unable to find the manual page you're looking for (even sometimes when it *should* find it). And there's a small delay before and after manual pages are shown. But overall, it's a handy utility to have around, especially when you want to learn more about a program without installing it or switching to a web browser.

Comment: On my MATE machine, I'm able to use `dman` and it shows manpages with no problem, but on my Cinnamon machine, I see `dman` creating a folder and it takes some seconds to download the file and then nothing happens, I don't know what's the problem, I tried `dman zfs` on both newly installed machines.

Comment: On mint mate 18 (ubuntu 16.04), I tried `dman ls`, `dman man`, `dman kubectl`, all of them shows nothing.

Comment: I'm noticing on LinuxMint Cinnamon 19.2 and 20 that is also shows nothing... However on debian if you install debian-goodies and debiman you can use dman just fine. It was introduced to Debian in around 2018 after this: https://github.com/Debian/debiman/issues/57